# I unwrapped texture image, how to wrap it back?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

so I have image texture wrapped on the object earlier, and I want to edit some painting on the image, so I unwrapped it, smart uv unwrap, and I paint something on it, now how to wrap it back? blender 2.81

Comment: What do you mean "wrap it back"? I don't think you need to do that.

Comment: the image is unwrapped, and so the color and shape on the image are not in the right spot to fit the object.

Comment: so I can not edit the image in blender?

Comment: Did you import an Image as plane, or a UV image texture.

Comment: i add a image to material property, the file is .dds file

Comment: Could you provide a picture?